# How to reference a constant in Spring Expression Language

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

i am quite new to Spring and i have a bean declaration as follows.

```
    <bean id="mybean" class="" scope="prototype">
       <property name='typeOf' value='#{typeOfBuilder.getKeyFor("OPEN_DATE").getId()}'/>    
</bean>
```

`typeOf` is a type of Integer which is the key of another table which `typeOfBuilder` builds by `Key` which is `OPEN_DATE` in this case.

this code works OK but have a limitation. `OPEN_DATE` is a constant in a `NON-MANAGE Spring Bean` something like follows.

```
public final class Constants
{
     public final static String KEY_FOR_OPEN_DATE = "OPEN_DATE";     
}
```

and is strongly recommend to be able to reference to it!!.

something like this.

```
<util:constant id="PATH_TO_CONSTANT" static-field="myPath"/>
<property name='typeOf' value='#{typeOfBuilder.getKeyFor(PATH_TO_CONSTANT).getId()}'/>
```

any help is hugely appreciate.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> The special 'T' operator can be used to specify an instance of java.lang.Class (the 'type'). Static methods are invoked using this operator as well.

Try the code below.

```
<property name='typeOf' value='#{typeOfBuilder.getKeyFor(T(some.package.Constants).KEY_FOR_OPEN_DATE).getId()}'/>
```